# Read Files name from assets and save name of files into buildConfigField on Gradle build time

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I have some files in assets directory. I want to read all files name and save as array/different string in buildConfigField at the time of build gradle.

I have no idea how to do this. Can somebody help.

Answer (score 1):

- in your build.gradle file,add `buildConfigField("String", "config", '\"name.json\"')` in defaultConfig
- in the directory path:app->main->assets,create your json file,like name.json
- create parse function,then you are able to parse it:

```kotlin
fun parseJson(context: Context): String {
    var result = ""
    val mAssets = context.assets.open("name.json")
    val length = mAssets.available()
    val buffer = ByteArray(length)
    mAssets.read(buffer)
    mAssets.close()
    result = String(buffer)
    RyLogger.d("TAG", "result: $result")
    return result
}
```